# webscrapping in R; structure too complex

Tags: r, web-scraping

I would like to scrape the contact info from this page, but the structure is too complex and I can't seem to identify the correct syntax to parse it.

https://freida.ama-assn.org/program/3200121017

This is what I've tried so far:

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, rvest)

url <- "https://freida.ama-assn.org/program/3200121017"

page <- read_html(url)

page %>%
html_elements(css = ".contact-info__contact__details")

page %>%
html_elements(xpath = "//*[contains(@class, 'contact-info__contacts__details')]")
```

Both return `character(0)`.

There's a lot of branching and the structure is pretty complex.
Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: does `rvest` support dynamic content? it looks like your page loads the data in using javascript.

Comment: @NickSlash I'm not sure, is there another package that does support dynamic content?

Comment: There are bindings for Selenium (RSelenium).

Comment: There's a typo in css selector, it should be ".contact-info__contact**s**__details" as in xpath, your xpath works fine for me. Though neither of those could return `character(0)`,  for empty element set you'd get `{xml_nodeset (0)}`, so perhaps you have gone bit too far when making this reprex minimal and have left out some relevant steps.

Answer (score 1):

Strange, `rvest` caught these infos for me

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

"https://freida.ama-assn.org/program/3200121017" %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_elements(".contact-info__contacts__details") %>% 
  html_text2() %>% 
  map(., ~ as_tibble(.x) %>% 
        separate_rows(value, sep = "\n"))

[[1]]
# A tibble: 8 × 1
  value                                
  <chr>                                
1 Michele Holloway Nichols MD          
2 Children's Hosp Alabama              
3 3rd Fl Dearth Tower/Sergio Stagno Ctr
4 1600 7th Ave S                       
5 Birmingham, AL 35233-1711            
6 Tel: (205) 638-9589                  
7 Fax: (205) 638-9977                  
8 E-mail: [email protected]            

[[2]]
# A tibble: 8 × 1
  value                                
  <chr>                                
1 Kimberly S Butler BSN                
2 Children's of Alabama                
3 3rd Fl Dearth Tower/Sergio Stagno Ctr
4 1600 7th Ave S                       
5 Birmingham, AL 35233-1711            
6 Tel: (205) 638-9589                  
7 Fax: (205) 638-9977                  
8 E-mail: [email protected]
```

Comment: I copy/pasted this code in a new R session, and I still get an empty list...does this mean there's something in my global settings that's throwing this off?